# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my build.gradel modul.app

PROBLEM org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'exclude module: 'support-v4'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'exclude module: 'support-v4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3'
}
```

[image: image is here]

I get tired with this problem when i  want to build this project to apk from buildbox by android studio

Comment: What way are you trying to generate the apk?

Comment: yes i want to generate the apk

Comment: Plese post your build.gradle from the main module app

Comment: Ok I posted please check it

Comment: Your gradle file looks ok. What build variant are you trying to execute?